# Select2 issues populating select

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, jquery-select2

This is my first try with select2 and I'm striking an issue which is probably something basic.

The select control code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="trade-select" name="trade-select">
     <option>...</option>
</select>
```

I'm using the following code to fetch data via a coldfusion function:

```
var options =
    {
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        ajax:
        {       
            url: "/ajax/search-trades.cfm",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (params) { return { query: params.term, 'groups_only': true }; },

            processResults: function (data, page)
            { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                alert(data.DATA); // see note further below
                return {results: data.DATA, more: false};
            }

        }
    };

    $('#trade-select').css('width', '100%').select2(options)
        .on('change', function(event)
        {
            if (this.value == '') return;
            $('#trade-select').val('').trigger('change');
        });
```

The raw JSON data returned from the call to the ajax URL is as follows:

```
{"COLUMNS":["TRADE_CATEGORY"],"DATA":[["Appliance Repairs"],["Furniture Repair"],["Painting &amp; Decorating"]]}
```

The alert in the above code returns the following, essentially a comma-delimited list with no brackets or anything:

> Appliance Repairs,Furniture Repair, Painting & Decorating

The issue is that the select is not populating with the returned data. I'm guessing it's something related to the format of the returned data.

Not sure if I've provided enough info, so let me know if you need anything else.

For any ColdFusion developer who may have an idea, the following is the ColdFusion template being called via the ajax url. I realise I could make a call directly to the CFC without an intermediary template:

```
<cfsilent>
<cfparam name="url.groups_only" default="true">
<cfparam name="url.query" default="">

<cfset oSystem = createObject("component","cfcs.system")>
<cfset qTradeCategories = oSystem.getTradeCategories(
    groups_only=url.groups_only,
    query=url.query)>
</cfsilent> 
<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(qTradeCategories)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: (Edit) Looking at the examples, select2 expects the data to be in a different than your cfm script is returning. [This example](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) suggests it expects an array of structures like this `[{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }]`. That is not what your CF script is returning.  Either modify the script to return the proper structure to begin with, or loop through the `data` object inside inside `processResults()` and build the structure select2 expects.

Comment: @Leigh, this is exactly my example in the answer :)

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try and get back. I'm sure you're right though.

Comment: @Dekel - Funny, my screen is still showing zero responses. Guess it is time to hit refresh manually :)

Comment: yeah, guess it is!

Comment: @user460114 did you check the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of the `results` should be a list of objects, where each object must have `id` and `text` keys:

```
[
  {
    'id': 4,
    'text': 'some text'
  },
  {
    'id': 3,
    'text': 'some other text'
  }
]
```

Since your data is not in that structure - you can make sure you send the correct structure, or generated it in javascript:

```
results: data.DATA.reduce(function(a, b) { 
      a.push({'id': b[0], 'text': b[0]})
      return a;
 }, [])
```

```js
data = [["Appliance Repairs"],["Furniture Repair"],["Painting &amp; Decorating"]]

console.log(data.reduce(function(a, b) { 
  a.push({'id': b[0], 'text': b[0]})
  return a;
}, []))
```

Comment: How would the answer look if I returned an ID with the raw JSON as follows: "DATA":[[1,"Appliance Repairs"],[26,"Furniture Repair"],[43,"Painting &amp; Decorating"]]  ?

Comment: You can change it to `a.push({'id': b[0], 'text': b[1]})`

Comment: Glad I could help :)